# Combined torque of torques at different points

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, magnetic-fields, reference-frames, torque

Let's say we have a constant (homogene) magnetic field $\boldsymbol{B}$ and a rigid object. Now let's say there are magnetic dipoles $\boldsymbol{p_{m,1}}$, $\boldsymbol{p_{m,2}}$,... $\boldsymbol{p_{m,n}}$ at locations $\boldsymbol{r_{1}}$, $\boldsymbol{r_{2}}$,... $\boldsymbol{r_{n}}$ inside that rigid object.

Of course, because $\boldsymbol{B}$ is constant, there are no aditional forces from dipoles. But each dipole generates a torque $\boldsymbol{p_{m,i}}\times \boldsymbol{B}$.

My question is how to calculate combined torque with respect to the point $\boldsymbol{r_{a}}$. For example: we might be interested in the case $\boldsymbol{r_{a}}=\boldsymbol{r_*}$ to determine the motion of such object.

Answer (score 2):

Torques are not "with respect to a point".  The moment about any point is independent of the point.  The resultant torque is just the vector sum of all the torques.

Comment: Okay, I was a bit confused abot that, because torques are usually calculated from forces and $\boldsymbol{\Delta r}\times\boldsymbol{F}$ depends on $\Delta r$. So If I understand it correctly, it does not matter where the magnetic moments are, the object always just rotates the same as if all magnetic moments were in the COM? I already used something like that as an approximation before, but I wasn't sure about it and it's still not obvious to me.

Comment: As long as the total force is zero, the moment is position indepenedent. That os why is is called a "torque" rather than a "moment"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did an experiment in Mathematica for electric dipoles, and it really is independant of the point

```
d=.001; F={1,0,0};
rs=RandomPoint[Ball[],10];
rpairs=({#,#}+{1,-1}Table[d RandomPoint[Ball[]],2])&/@rs;
ListPointPlot3D@rpairs
```

and then

```
ra=RandomPoint[Ball[]];
Total[(#[[1]]\[Cross]F-#[[2]]\[Cross]F)&/@rpairs]
Total[(-#\[Cross]F)&/@((Differences/@rpairs)[[;;,1]])]
```

and you always get the same result, which ok, I remember the theorm, that if sum of forces is zero..., but I still don't see the mathematical reason, why it's just a sum of torques.